# Wordpress registered menu not working but the default is working fine

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I have a child theme and registered a menu thru functions.php file.

```html
function register_new_menu(){
  register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-two'    => esc_html__( 'Menu Two', 'lsx' ),
    'mobile-menu' => esc_html__( 'Mobile Menu', 'lsx' ),
  ));
}

add_action('init', 'register_new_menu');
```

and I have to show it using the wp_nav_menu() function, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know why.

here's the code for the header.

```html
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'menu-two' ) ){ ?>
  <nav class="primary-navbar collapse navbar-collapse">
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-two',
    'depth'          => 3,
    'container'      => false,
    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'walker'         => new LSX_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
    ) );
    ?>
   </nav>
   <?php
   }
?>
```

I also have additional question why my wp_debug not showing any error message?

[image: here's a screenshot of the result]

the first one doesn't show the menu and the second one, which is the default primary menu, works fine.

Thanks in advance for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Try using the function "get_registered_nav_menus()" just to see if the menu is properly registered and it is returned via this function.

Comment: ok I'll try it.. Thanks!

Comment: it does show all the registered menus. Idk why it doesn't show

Comment: @zipkundan can you help me with figuring it out with my site? the code get_registered_nav_menus() works fine and shows the registered menus. but when I use wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=> $location ) ); Its not actually working